# React Snapshot Jest testing, Conditional rendering

Tags: jestjs, snapshot

I am new to Jest and testing in general, I am writing a Jest snapshot testing for a react code. The code renders Link component with corresponding attributes, and an Icon if an href exists.How can I write the snapshot for it?
The code is lengthy, but This is the conditional rendering part:

```
<Typography
        variant="h4"
        component="h1"
        gutterBottom
      >
        {serverPublicationResponse?.title}
        { externalLink && (
          <Link
            target="_blank"
            underline="hover"
            aria-label={serverPublicationResponse?.title}
            href={serverPublicationResponse?.doiLink}
          >
            <Launch sx={{ fontSize: '1.75rem', ml: 0.35 }} />
          </Link>
        )}
      </Typography>
```

And this is the Jest test so far, Is there a way I can write the whole snapshot test in just one block of test?:

```
describe('pagePublication', () => {
  test('should match with the previous snapshot', (done) => {
    const x: Publication = { key: '', title: '', year: 1 };
    const y: PublicationKeyphrase = { keyphrases: [] };
    const testRenderer = TestRenderer.create(
      <PagePublication
        serverPublicationResponse={x}
        serverPublicationKeyphraseResponse={y}
      />,
    );
    expect(testRenderer.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
    done();
  });
});
```